# how can i import package from node_modules when use express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, import

**when import a package this error appear:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

**and when add **" ./ " , " ../ "** this error appear**

> GET http://localhost:8080/js/axios net:: ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "fives",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "game",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./app.js"
  },
  "author": "ayah alrifai",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import path from 'path';

const app=express();
const port="8080";

app.use('/image', express.static('./public/img'));
app.use('/css', express.static('./public/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static('./js'));

app.get('/wait', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(path.resolve()+'/html/await.html'));
});

app.get('/play', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(path.resolve()+'/html/play.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

wait.js

```
import {getWaitedPlayers,createUser,deleteUser,isSelected,action} from "./fivesApi.js";
//code
```

fivesApi.js

```
import axios from "axios";
//code
```

tree

```
.
├── html
│   ├── wait.html
│   └── play.html
├── app.js
├── js
│   ├── wait.js
│   ├── fivesApi.js
│   └── play.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── public
    ├── css
    │   └── fives.css
    └── img
        ├── 2.png
        ├── 5.png
        └── ayah.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent 2 hours and finally find a solution, the first thing you need to do is

```
npm i parcel-bundler -D
```

> then package.json add the following two-line of codes

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "parcel index.html",
"build": "parcel build index.html"
}
```

> finally npm run dev.

and if you still have trouble, [please open this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-axios-vanilla-js) link it just saves me so many hours.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a (somewhat) similar situation. Posting in case it helps someone. I do feel there's a better way, but it escapes me for now.

context: using an express.js server to serve up an entire client site that lives in a subfolder, and linking up a socket.io client via esm in the client JS module.

1. In the express server, define a path to your `node_modules` directory:

   const DIR_ROOT = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
   app.use('/node_modules', express.static(join(DIR_ROOT, "node_modules")));
2. In the client module, provide the explicit pathname exactly as it appears in your file system:

   import { io } from "/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.esm.min.js";
3. And of course, make sure this second bit is in a js module, so the script import looks like this:

Comment: Huh, not sure why the SO markup isn't formatting my code properly. Perhaps some nice mod can come and clean that up. I'm stumped.